# QProcess Backup Database on QT C++

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qprocess

I want to backup my database with qprocess in QT program, the code is as follows, but 0kb occurs when backing up and when I look at the error Qprocess: Destroyed while process("mysqldump.exe") is still runnuing.

```
QProcess dump(this);
QStringlist args;
QString path="C:/Users/mahmut/Desktop/dbbackupfile/deneme.sql";
args<<"-uroot"<<"-proot"<<"kopuz"<<">";
dump.setStandardOutputFile(path);
dump.start("mysqldump.exe",args);

if(!dump.waitForStarted(1000))
{
qDebug()<<dump.errorString();
}
```

Can you help to me? ı do not understand this error and okb back up file.

Comment: Check the static convenience functions of `QProcess`, maybe you want to use those. Then again maybe not, especially if this is a GUI program.

Comment: thank you, how to create backup database file inside zip file on qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program terminates before process finished, you need to either use `static bool QProcess::startDetached(program, arguments, workingDirectory)` or add `dump.waitForFinished();` to the end.

Also, you dont need to add ">" to arguments. You already redirected output with `dump.setStandardOutputFile(path)`, ">" does not work with process as it requires shell to execute command, `QProcess` does not use shell it just runs one process not shell expression.

Comment: thank you, how to create backup database file inside  zip file on qt.